# OLAP Cube to Elasticsearch with Logstash

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, logstash, olap-cube

I'm looking at a POC that is supposed to import an olap cube into Elasticsearch. We have big plans for overhauling our current processes, but at present my team is stuck on finding the best way to clone the cube into Elasticsearch.

The idea is to provide an exact replica of the cube data so we can recreate reports with zero user-facing changes and phase in adaptations/new stuff in bite-sized chunks.

There definitely doesn't appear to be a preexisting input for Logstash, so what's the next best thing?

Comment: I went through that migration (OLAP -> ES) 3 years ago, I started out with  the same idea, i.e. reuse OLAP stuff as much as possible, but I ended up scratching it all away and restarted on a saner basis. It won't be possible to provide an exact replica of an OLAP cube, because the concepts are different. You can achieve much more with ES than you ever would with a cube, so it's worth spending a bit of time analyzing what you need to do and how you want to do it.

Comment: ES is equivalent to your staging database or your System of Record, **not** the analytic engine. You are trying to convert apples to apple pie. OLAP is used to accelerate ad-hoc reporting on top of one or more star schemas. It is *not* the star schema itself.

Comment: The real thing here is trying to introduce needed infrastructure updates without risking business-driver buy-in. I get the differences in the technology, but the question comes from a strategic/business need.

Comment: Fair enough, though I think the question is a bit too broad to be answered precisely in a few paragraphs so as to be useful at all. Feel free to provide as many details as you deem necessary to receive quality inputs from the community. In short, help us help you.